# How to change the timezone of a browser temporarily?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, timezone

For some test use cases, I need to change the time-zone or time-zones that my browser have. A time-zone is read by js by a web application **I'm working on**.

Is there an easy way to change a time-zone of a browser?